# Bizarre connectivity issue

Tags: linux-mint, firefox, chrome, internet, connectivity

I just got the most bizarre connectivity issue.

WiFi connects and also cable. I can ping and even connect to a VPM (forticlient), but the browser can't reach any page. It throws "server not found" after a very long wait.

Tried both Firefox and Chrome. The weird thing is Tor does work and when I'm connected to a work VPN the browsers DO work. I'm guessing this is a config issue maybe? Please help. I'm in quarantine and can't do my job without internet.

Content of my /etc/resolv.config

```
1 # Generated by expressvpn
2 search expressvpn
3 nameserver 10.43.0.1
```

Comment: DNS issues? /etc/resolv.conf got rewritten by work's VPN and not set back correctly after? could also be a proxy setting, pointing to work and thus not available

Comment: I usually use a fixed dns (1.1.1.1) but i switched back to automatic, didn't help.
what i have in my etc/resolv.conf is:

  1 # Generated by expressvpn
  2 search expressvpn
  3 nameserver 10.47.0.1

expressvpn is my private vpn, is this the problem?

Answer (score 1):

My personal VPN wrote over my resolv.conf file and didn't return it to normal.

What i did was comment the old content and add two new dns servers to the file, and it works. this is how the new file looks like:

```
1 # Generated by expressvpn
2 # search expressvpn
3 # nameserver 10.47.0.1
    ^old content^
4 nameserver 8.8.8.8
5 nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Many thanks to A.B for pointing me in the right direction